# Can not set focus and type text in TextBox placed in <controls:PageHeader.PrimaryCommands>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, template10

I am using Template10. This part of code create toolbar with TextBox named searchTextBox and button. Problem is I can not write any character to the TextBox . I can paste some text by right click. This TextBox is enabled and is not read only.

```
   <!--  header  -->
    <controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" x:Uid="LoadViewHeader"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" 
                         RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True">

        <!--  primary commands  -->
        <controls:PageHeader.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="searchButton"  Width="250" Padding="0">
                <AppBarButton.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox Name="searchTextBox" x:Uid="LoadViewSearchBox" Width="250" Height="32" Margin="0,8,0,0" 
                                 Text="{Binding Path=TextToSearch, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="SearchTextBox_TextChanged" />

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </AppBarButton.Template>
            </AppBarButton>

            <AppBarButton Name="searchTextBoxButton" x:Uid="LoadViewSearchTextBoxButton" Icon="Find" Label="Search" />
            <AppBarSeparator/>
        </controls:PageHeader.PrimaryCommands>
    </controls:PageHeader>
```

Comment: you definitely don't need that TextChanged event if you are doing MVVM, it might even get in the way.

Comment: I know it is debug only to check behavior. Placing clipboard text by right click to the text box enable change value. Setting breakpoint to TextChanged event procedure helps me to inspect state of code.

Comment: you could do that in the viewmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio team expert identified this problem as error in UWP.

See - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/59249/text-box-in-page-header-is-partially-editable.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used two headers one to show text header second for search.

```
    <!--  page header  -->
    <controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" x:Uid="LoadViewHeader" Width="auto" 
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.LeftOf="searchPageHeader">
        <controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="Settings" />
        </controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
    </controls:PageHeader>

    <!--  searching header  -->
    <controls:PageHeader x:Name="searchPageHeader" Width="auto" EllipsisVisibility="Collapsed"
               RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
        <controls:PageHeader.Content>
            <AutoSuggestBox Name="searchTextBox" x:Uid="LoadViewSearchBox" Width="250" Height="32" Margin="0,8,8,0" QueryIcon="Find" >
                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="QuerySubmitted">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SearchCommand}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </AutoSuggestBox>

        </controls:PageHeader.Content>
    </controls:PageHeader>
```